# Remote execution stops when local computer boots

Tags: linux, shell, process, remote-execution

When I run a process on a remote Linux machine, the process stops if the connection is terminated for some cause. This behavior is reasonable, because otherwise irrelevant processes would keep running forever.

However, is there a way to prevent this from happening? Namely, I want to open a remote shell, run a process and direct its output to a log file, and log out - but keep the process running.

Thanks,

Udi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well first option can be to spawn you program as another process with the & operator like

```
$ myprogram > file.log &
```

Or you can have a look at the [screen command](http://www.oreillynet.com/linux/cmd/cmd.csp?path=s/screen) where you can store and retrieve your terminal sessions.

Answer (score 3):

You can either use a [screen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Screen) session or push the process to background [disconnecting it from the shell](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/1025/runs-a-command-without-hangups.).

also check,

> [**shopt**](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html) -u huponexit

Comment: That's great - thanks! Perhaps nohup will work, too.